# How to get selected item in dropdown list using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two multi select lists.

On click/select of any item from 1st list, I want to remove the selected item from 1st list and to move the same to 2nd list and vice versa.

I have tried `ng-change` and `ng-click` but not getting idea.

Below is my code

**1st List**

```
<select style="min-height:200px"
        multiple class="form-control"
        ng-model="listOneItem"
        ng-options="listOneItem.Name for listOneItem in listOneItems track by listOneItem.Name"
        ng-change="moveItemsToSecondList();"></select>
```

**2nd List**

```
 <select style="min-height:200px"
            multiple class="form-control"
            ng-model="listTwoItem"
            ng-options="listTwoItem.Name for listTwoItem in listTwoItems track by listTwoItem.Name"
            ng-change="moveItemsToFirstList();"></select>
```

Angularjs

```
  $scope.moveItemsToSecondList= function () {
    alert(listOneItem[0].Name);
  };

  $scope.listOneItems= [{
    Name: 'Independence Day'
  }, {
    Name: 'Labor Day'
  }, {
    Name: 'Thanksgiving Day'
  }, {
    Name: 'Chrismas Day'
  }];
```

I didn't write functionality to move yet because I am not able to call my methods. i.e. I just put an alert in the method as shown.

Comment: Is your alert shows anything?

Comment: no method didn't call yet :(

Comment: guys any idea please...

Comment: ng-change should fire. Please show more code, especially your controller function and that you specify this correctly in the template. Is your select even populated with your array?

Comment: @Andreas : Its ``multiple`` multi select list, so ng-change might not working, Just guessing

Comment: ngChange works fine with ´multiple´. I checked it.

Comment: yup, ngChange is working

Answer (score 3):

Hi I have created jsfiddle demo here
I have added some logic in it that my help you
http://jsfiddle.net/qjcqwhsw/1/

```
$scope.moveItemsToSecondList= function (items) {
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var index = $scope.listOneItems.indexOf(items[i]);
        $scope.listTwoItems.push(items[i]);
        $scope.listOneItems.splice(index, 1);            
    }

};
```

Comment: I am getting -1 index always by using your code. Can you please check if its fine

Comment: can you provide details plesae